# How can I split a text file by a specific string that has wilcards?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a text file that has solutions from a textbook and I'm attempting to split each solution into its own text file, and after searching through SO, I can't seem to find a solution that's elegant.

Each solution is prefaced with the problem number such as `*1-3;` or `*4-2;`.

I can read in the file and store each line in a list, but I'm having trouble actually processing the list to split by the header.

Here's a pastebin with a few of the solutions straight from the .txt: http://pastebin.com/ntSXLn72

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import re

file_name = "" # put the txt file you're working on

new_header = None

for line in open(file_name,"r").readlines():
    if re.search("^[*][0-9]+[-][0-9]+[;]", line):
        if new_header:
            new_header.close() 
        new_header = open("%s_section:%s" % (file_name, line), "w")
    if new_header:
        new_header.write(line)

if new_header:
    new_header.close
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [re.split](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re

with open('text.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

solutions = re.split('\*[0-9]\-[0-9];',text)
```

That regex will look for `*<any number>-<any number>;`, and split the full text by anything matching. You may have to do a little cleanup for empty members.